# Cloudinary REST api destroy doesn't work?

Tags: php, curl, post, cloudinary

I'm trying to delete an image in Cloudinary but it doesn't work, where am I doing wrong?

this code returns nothing result

```
$api_key = "----";
$api_secret = "---";
$timestamp = time();
$signature = sha1("timestamp=".$timestamp.$api_secret);

$postRequest = array(
'public_id' => "folder/sample_public_id",
'timestamp' => $timestamp,
'api_key' => $api_key,
'signature' => $signature,
'resource_type' => 'image',
'invalidate' => true);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/CLOUDNAME/image/destroy");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postRequest));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,3);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
print_r( curl_exec($ch) );
```

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a fixable problem. You need to provide more precise details of your issue, based on your attempts to debug this code. We can't guess what exact problem you're having. cURL can report errors, and can also show you things like HTTP response headers, so you can get more information about what happened to the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having additional details about the issue and just by looking at the code, I see a reason which would explain why such a request is not succeeding.

When you are [generating authentication signatures](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#generating_authentication_signatures) for API calls to Cloudinary, you need to sign all parameters you're passing as part of your request apart from `file`, `cloud_name`, `resource_type` and your `api_key`.

In your case, you are only signing the `timestamp` but in your request, you are also passing the `public_id` and `invalidate` parameters. Therefore, you need to include them in your signature generation line.

Note that the parameters need to be ordered alphabetically when signing and the `api_secret` concatenated at the end. In this case, your 4th line to generate the signature should look like this:

```
$signature = sha1("invalidate=true&public_id=folder/sample_public_id&timestamp=".$timestamp.$api_secret);
```

As a first step, I'd recommend making the above changes and sending another request. If that doesn't succeed then please update the post with additional information.

Comment: thank you very much sir, its worked